# While comparing a query which if results to be true, i want to display a text field. But the field just disappears

Tags: php, html

I want to display a text field if the comparison of two queries from the database comes to be true. But the text field doesn't show up.

I have tried making individual 'if' blocks but it's not working.

```
 <?php
        if ($row['status']=="in process" || $row['status']=="On the way" ){
             if ($row['rider_status']=="pending"){ ?>
                   <input type="submit" name="accept" value="accept">
 <?php } ?>
                   <input type="submit" name="decline" value="decline"><br>
  <?php
                     if ($row['rider_status']=="accepted") { ?>
          <input type="submit" name="on_the_way" value="Mark as On the way">
  <?php }

 if($row['rider_status']="on the way") {?>
               <input type="text" name="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP" ><br>
                   <?php if($error=="wrong otp") echo "wrong OTP"; ?>
               <input type="submit" name="delivered" value="Mark as Delivered"><?php 
     }
   }
  ?>
```

I want it to display the text field.

Comment: Can you add the comment to the place in your code example and explain how it behaves and what do you expect? It's not very clear to me. But after a brief look I think you are missing `==` instead of `=` at line `if($row['rider_status']="on the way") {?>`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Even using == doesn't help. Actually what I am trying to do is getting status from $_row['status'] and then according to it show two buttons accept or decline. If clicked on 'accept'. It will show to enter otp. but this is the field which is not being shown